# Where is this python method defined?

Tags: python

I'm currently reading the code of virt-manager/virt-clone, but did not do much python before.

Here is the important parts of the code:

---

https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/blob/master/virt-clone#L169

```
conn = cli.getConnection(options.connect)
design = Cloner(conn)
```

https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/blob/master/virtinst/cli.py#L263

```
from .connection import VirtualConnection
conn = VirtualConnection(uri)
```

https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/blob/master/virtinst/connection.py#L35

```
class VirtualConnection(object):
```

https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/blob/master/virtinst/cloner.py#L591

```
return self.conn.lookupByName(name)
```

---

The last line looks like there is a method `lookupByName` called for an object of class `VirtualConnection`. However I cannot find such a method defined in that class and it does not have a parent class to get such a method from, either.

Can you help me spot the place where `lookupByName` is defined?

What might be a good way to find such an answer myself? (debugger, etc?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lookupByName` method of the `virConnect` object is defined in C as part of libvirt's Python bindings. The following code forwards the attribute accesses from it to that object which was returned by `libvirt.openAuth` and assigned to `self._libvirtconn`:

https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/blob/master/virtinst/connection.py#L94

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if attr in self.__dict__:
        return self.__dict__[attr]

    # Proxy virConnect API calls
    libvirtconn = self.__dict__.get("_libvirtconn")
    return getattr(libvirtconn, attr)
```

This causes `conn.lookupByName` to be `conn._libvirtconn.lookupByName`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't investigated your case, but in Python methods can be dynamically added to a class or to an instance

```
class A:
    def a(self):
        print 'a'

class C(A):
    def c(self):
        print 'c'

def foo(arg):
    print 'foo',arg

a = C()
print dir(a)

C.f = foo

a.a()
a.c()
a.f()
print dir(a)
```

the result is:

```
['__doc__', '__module__', 'a', 'c']
a
c
foo <__main__.C instance at 0x024CB9B8>
['__doc__', '__module__', 'a', 'c', 'f']
```

As you can see the second call to dir shows new method 'f'. So in some cases it might be tricky to find the origin of that.

Answer (score 0):

The VirtualConnection class you refer to has an implementation of `__getattr__`, which is a method that will be called when an attribute cannot be resolved.

This `__getattr__` method looks up attributes on a "_libvirtconn" attribute of the VirtualConnection instance.

See also: [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**getattr**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)